Why do I get "The endpoint only accepts POST requests. Received a GET request" error when authenticating with SSO on iOS App but not on Safari
I have an app on the apple store that needs to use SSO to login. When attempting to login with Microsoft, everything works perfectly fine on regular safari, but when I try it on the app from the apple store, after I enter my password (which should then prompt for 2fa), I get an error that says "The endpoint only accepts POST requests. Received a GET request."
After looking at the network tab, I found it interesting that there wasn't a request being sent at all after entering my password.
Note: This app was made using the PWA builder website.this is the error that pops up after entering my password into the login.microsoft page
I have made sure to put all the necessary domains into the WKAppBoundDomains list in the info.plist. I have tried clearing all cookies, but that did not help
We are using WorkOS to get the URL to login.mocrosoft.online which is where the user finishes up their auth
public async Task<SystemMessage> SsoLoginAsync(string email)
{
    WorkOS.WorkOS.SetApiKey(_settings.WorkOsApiKey); 
    SSOService ssoService = new();
    
    ApplicationUser user = await _db.Users
        .Include(o => o.Client)
        .Where(o => 
            o.Email == email 
            && o.IsActive == true
        ).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    if (user == null) { return Notification.ErrorMessage("Could not Authenticate"); }
    string orgId = user.Client?.SsoOrganizationId;
    if (orgId == null) { return Notification.ErrorMessage("Could not Authenticate"); }

    GetAuthorizationURLOptions options = new()
    {
        ClientId = _settings.WorkOsClientId
        , Organization = orgId
        , RedirectURI = _settings.BaseUrl + "login?fromSso=true"
    };
    string ssoUrl = ssoService.GetAuthorizationURL(options);
   
    return Notification.SuccessMessage(
        ""
        , value: new { ssoUrl, email }
        , showSystemMessage: false
    );
}


I was able to fix the issue. I was not aware that the settings.swift file had to match the WKAppBoundDomains in the info.plist.
In Settings.swift, there was an array of strings called allowedOrigins. After matching this array of strings to the WKAppBoundDomains in info.plist, everything worked as expected.
